# img from header div doesn't go in front of content div

Tags: html, css

I can't make my `.content-panel` and `#panel-design` float on the right of the `.content`  because of the header design img `#searchbar-container`.
I already tried using `z-index` with different values.
I want to place `.content-panel` and `#panel-design` on the right side of the `.content` while having `#searchbar-container` above the divs

```
<body>
        <div class="header">
            <img id="searchbar-container" src="images/searchbar1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="sidebar"></div>
            <div class="content-panel">
                <div id="panel-design"></div>
                   <!--main content here-->
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

the css:

```
    .content {
    position: relative;
    max-width: @width;
    height: 768px;;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
   }
       .content-panel {
        position: absolute;
        float: right;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 753px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
        z-index: -2;
    }
    #panel-design{
        float: right;
        width: 685px;
        height: 375px;
        background-color: red;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    .sidebar{
        width: 285px;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Can't post the whole thing. But this is what I need to achieve, basically the gray image above is the `#searchbar-container` and the picture of Depp is the `#panel-design` in front of the `.content-panel`.

[image]

So far this is what my page looks like:

[image]

the blue div is the `.content-panel`

the red div is the `#panel-design`

the gray img above is the `#searchbar-container`

`.content` doesn't have a background color but its size is pass the curve of `#searchbar-container`

Comment: `position:absolute` and `float:right` don't work together, FYI.  Pick one or the other.  Additionally, you aren't showing us all of your css, so it's quite challenging to know.

Comment: Could you post an image of the desired result?

Comment: @cale_b that's a typo, I noticed that.

Comment: @shin-shan where is the header class??? Otherwise not possible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

So what I understand from you question is that, you want `#searchbar-container` to overlap your `#panel-design`.

one way of doing it would be to make `.header` div fixed, but you might not want that because then it becomes independent of the scroll.

Another way I came up with uses `absolute` position you can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tx6bS/)

Comment: well it certainly is under the `#searchbar-container` but it 'went out' of `.content` div which is 980px in middle of the page, `.content` serves as the page wrapper that keeps everything (aside from the header) in the middle of the browser

Comment: is `.content` position relative?

Comment: yes, I updated the css code above
if I remove the `#panel-design`, everything is in proper place. `z-index` doesn't work, not sure why.

Comment: and is it still out of `.content` ?

Comment: no, but it stops before the `#searchbar-container`, meaning it doesn't reach the right margin of `.content` I'll put a picture of what I have now

Comment: do you want a full page header or an image that stretches to 100% of the header, the header is full width http://jsfiddle.net/tx6bS/1/

Comment: your `.content` has a width of 980px while `.content-panel` has a width of 753px, that is why it is not reaching the right margin..

Comment: my header is already set to 100% width, it doesn't have any problem. I think it's because `searchbar-container` is colliding with `content-panel` and `panel-design` thought the `content` itself is in proper place. I'll recheck the code and get back to you. thanks!

Comment: that was intended, the 227px was for another div which is on the left